# Why does Find My Mac require a Recovery partition?

Tags: macos, recovery, find-my-mac

Just for my curiosity and knowledge, about Find My Mac, one of the condition is to have a local OS X Recovery Partition installed.

Why?

Answer (score 1):

Find My Mac requires a recovery partition as it is this partition which is used to control the FMM status outside of the OS. For instance, Find My Mac can retain the ability to control the Mac even if OS X is removed and Windows is installed (for example).